# How to query python data frame against row of other data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe (Df1) of say 100 rows.  I also have a dataframe (df2) which contains 1 row.  For each data frame, a row represents a property.  The columns in question are 'NIY' and 'Purchase Price'.  I want to write a function that queries DF1 to show results where the NIY is within 0.1 of DF2 and the purchase price is within 2,000,000 of DF2.

DF1 contains multiple columns, of which contain 'NIY' & 'Purchase Price'.

| Purchase_Price | NIY | Purchaser |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 230000000 | 0.15 | GS |
| 30000000 | 0.08 | JKK |

See code below

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('CopyTransactions.csv', header=3)

df2 = {'Purchase_Price': [25300000], 'NIY': [0.078]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)
df1.query('Purchase_Price > 1000000 & NIY > 0.09')

df1.query('NIY within range g.0['NIY'] + or - 0.01 
     & Purchase_price within range g.0['Purchase_Price'] + or - 2,000,000)
```

The code works until the bottom part, I want to work out how to correctly code the bottom section. (the 0 in the bottom code means index 0/first row)

Thanks!

Comment: "I also have a dataframe (df2) which contains 1 row", but `df2` here has 2 rows. Also, we don't have your csv file `'CopyTransactions.csv'`. And you're querying on a dataframe called `df`, but `df` is not declared. If you want help, you need to provide enough code and data to reproduce your problem

Comment: next, I would not put spaces in your column headers. Use an underscore. IE `df2 = {'Purchase_Price': [25300000, 34400000], 'NIY': [0.078, 0.11]}`. That way, `df2.query('Purchase_Price > 1000000 & NIY > 0.09')` will work

Comment: "I want to write a function that queries DF1 to show results where the NIY is within 0.1 of DF2". Then why are you putting `+ or - 0.02`?

Comment: Thanks, i'll edit that.  Essentially I want to be able to query within a range, rather than > or < and replace the number (e.g 0.078) with df2['NIY'].

Comment: Gotcha. Put up small sample data set of df1 (like how you did for df2)

Comment: I don't think pandas supports range with the .query method. Do you have to use `.query()`? There's easier was to do it

Comment: No, however .query() is the only way I know! Either that or use SQLite to query.

Answer (score 2):

With `query`, you can try:

```
>>> df1.query("@df2.Purchase_Price.iat[0]-2000000 <= Purchase_Price <= @df2.Purchase_Price.iat[0]+2000000 and @df2.NIY.iat[0]-0.1 <= NIY <= @df2.NIY.iat[0]+0.1")

   Purchase_Price   NIY Purchaser
2        23500000  0.08       FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of filtering/slicing your dataframe.

I would store the values from df2 as a variable. Then could use `pandas` `.between()`

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = {'Purchase_Price': [23000000, 30000000, 26300000], 
       'NIY': [0.15, 0.08, 0.069],
       'Purchaser': ['GS','JKK','JJK']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)

df2 = {'Purchase_Price': [25300000], 'NIY': [0.078]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)


price_check = df2.iloc[0]['Purchase_Price']
niy_check = df2.iloc[0]['NIY']

price = 2000000
niy = 0.01

df = df1[(df1['Purchase_Price'].between(price_check - price, price_check + price)) 
     & (df1['NIY'].between(niy_check - niy, niy_check + niy))]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

   Purchase_Price    NIY Purchaser
2        26300000  0.069       JJK
```

**In a function:**

```
import pandas as pd


def filter_df(df1, df_check, price_thresh, niy_thresh):
    price_check = df_check.iloc[0]['Purchase_Price']
    niy_check = df_check.iloc[0]['NIY']
    
    df = df1[(df1['Purchase_Price'].between(price_check - price_thresh, price_check + price_thresh)) 
     & (df1['NIY'].between(niy_check - niy_thresh, niy_check + niy_thresh))]
    
    return df

df = {'Purchase_Price': [23000000, 30000000, 26300000], 
       'NIY': [0.15, 0.08, 0.069],
       'Purchaser': ['GS','JKK','JJK']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)

df_check = {'Purchase_Price': [25300000], 'NIY': [0.078]}
df_check = pd.DataFrame(data=df_check)


new_df = filter_df(df, df_check, price_thresh=2000000, niy_thresh=0.01)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I wasn't aware of the between function. Cheers